# Difference between const and readonly in typescript

Tags: typescript

Constant vs readonly in typescript

Declaring a variable as `readonly` will not allow us to override even if they are public properties.

How const behaves,

```
const SOME_VARIABLE:number = 10;
```

If I override its value, how will it work?

Comment: See also [readonly, difference from const](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/readonly.html#difference-from-const) (TypeScript Deep Dive book).

Comment: [updated link to book](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/readonly#difference-from-const)

Comment: The book link is gold; it explains the difference in half the words of these answers.

Answer (score 156):

A `const` variable cannot be re-assigned, just like a `readonly` property.

Essentially, when you define a property, you can use `readonly` to prevent re-assignment. This is actually only a compile-time check.

When you define a `const` variable (and target a more recent version of JavaScript to preserve `const` in the output), the check is also made at runtime.

So they effectively both do the same thing, but one is for variables and the other is for properties.

```
const x = 5;

// Not allowed
x = 7;


class Example {
    public readonly y = 6;
}

var e = new Example();

// Not allowed
e.y = 4;
```

Important note... "cannot be re-assigned" is not the same as immutability.

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];

// Not allowed
myArr = [4, 5, 6]

// Perfectly fine
myArr.push(4);

// Perfectly fine
myArr[0] = 9;
```

Comment: I m confused with this **// Perfectly fine `myArr[0] = 9;`**. How you can call it to be a constant then?

Comment: @Aravind An array in JS/TS is a mutable object. So `myArr` is a constant reference to a mutable object.  You can't point it at some other array, but you can change the contents of the array.  You (`myArr`) have picked up a box (`[1, 2, 3]`) and glued it to your hands (`const`).  The glue means you can't let it go and pick up another box (`myArr = [4, 5, 6]`) or anything else (`myArr = 'something else'`).  But the glue doesn't stop someone from putting something into the box (`myArr.push(4)`) or replacing some of its contents (`myArr[0]=9`).

Comment: And the same as with `Array` happens with `Object`... It's our responsability to turn them inmutable - they are NOT.

Comment: Just to add to this, in TypeScript you can use `ReadonlyArray<T>` to prevent push / pop / shift etc. Compile-time only, but excellent for public library APIs etc.

Comment: Summary: they are the same but const is for variables & readonly is for class properties.

Comment: // Perfectly fine myArr[0] = 9;. How you can call it to be a constant then?

Because variable "myArr" cannot be assigned to a different array pointer.

Comment: @Fritz it's just that in JS const used with objects and arrays makes it impossible to reassign to the const variable, but does not prevent from modifying the "insides".

Comment: I'd like to add a reason that "readonly" is meant mostly for being used in classes: with const we would need to initialise the properties at declaration time, while in classes most properties are initialised with value by constructor after they've been declared previously. Declaring them const would cause an error when trying to assign a value in constructor. However if you initlise at declaration time and the property is not meant to be changed, use of const is fine.

Answer (score 42):

One of the key difference between const and readonly is in how it works with the array. (appart form already ans diff)
You have to use

```
readonly Array<T>
```

while working with Array,
where T is generic type(google it for more).

when u declare any array as const, you can perform operations on array which may change the array elements.
for ex.

```
const Arr = [1,2,3];

Arr[0] = 10;   //OK
Arr.push(12); // OK
Arr.pop(); //Ok

//But
Arr = [4,5,6] // ERROR
```

But in case of readonly Array you can not change the array as shown above.

```
arr1 : readonly Array<number> = [10,11,12];

arr1.pop();    //ERROR
arr1.push(15); //ERROR
arr1[0] = 1;   //ERROR
```

Comment: I don't think this is actually relevant to the question at hand (keyword "readonly" vs keyword "const"), although I didn't know that ReadonlyArray existed.

Comment: But the answer matches the actual behavior of readonly VS const keywords. with the readonly, you can't modify in any way the object/array and the object/array properties/elements. It's used mainly along state management systems in which we want to modify values only from pure functions collections, and nowhere else.

Comment: its not directly related to the question asked, but appreciate the additional information

Answer (score 19):

both:

- can be changed (for example by `.push()` if array)

const:

- can't be reassigned
- used for variables

readonly:

- can be reassigned but only inside constructor
- used for properties (class member)

Comment: `readonly` doesn't allow you to do `.push()` on arrays: `Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly any[]'. ts(2339)`

Comment: The remark about `readonly` and the constructor is a key element left out of other answers. Thanks!

Comment: and official documentation links are a key thing left out of this and other answers also

Comment: ```as const``` also does not let you use ```.push()``` on arrays:
```Property 'push' does not exist on type...```

Answer (score 13):

1. I think that the accepted answer didn't emphasized enough that `const` is expected to be used with variables while `readonly` with class/interface properties.
2. `readonly` is checked only during type-checking (compile time) while `const` is checked during runtime
3. declaring a property to be `readonly` doesn't mean that its value can't be changed: it means that the property cannot be re-assigned, example:

---

```
interface Person {
    readonly info: { name: string; age: number };
}

//create a new person
// ...

person.info.age += 1; // this is valid
person.info = { name: "Johnny", age: 15 }; // this is invalid!
```

4. Since TS 3.4 there are [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) which are used to define `types`:

---

```
// Type 'readonly [10, 20]'
let y = [10, 20] as const;

// Type '{ readonly text: "hello" }'
let z = { text: "hello" } as const;
```

For more, see [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties)

Answer (score 8):

as said in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#readonly-vs-const

> The easiest way to remember whether to use readonly or const is to ask whether you’re using it on a variable or a property. Variables use const whereas properties use readonly.

as it displayed in below image if you declare const in defining a property you will get an error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SFHm.png

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for both words is probably that it's easier to implement than the alternative.

In C++, for instance, classes can have const members.  But C++ has special syntax to initialize the constants before the constructor is run, so there's never really any "assignment" to the const going on, like:

```
class TestClass {
    const int _x;
    TestClass(int x) : _x(x) {}
}
```

The _x(x) initializes the _x variable before the constructor is called.

In Typescript, if they wanted to allow members to be declared const and were serious about the variables being const, they would need to add similar syntax.

"readonly" isn't really the same as const.  It means, I think, something slightly different.  It means "allow assignment inside the constructor, but then no more."

Answer (score -1):

**const**

1. constant in compile time
2. must be initialized on its declaration
3. can be declared in methods

**readonly**

1. constant in execution time
2. don't need to be initialized on its declaration
3. can't be declared in methods, only constructor or self declaration

Comment: `readonly` is not constant during execution, `const` is. Both are also constant at compile time.