# Difference between as const and readonly?

Tags: typescript

Tested two identical things in typescript and little bit confused whats difference between them.

**ReadOnly**

```
const arr: readonly string[] = ["test1", "test2"];

arr.push(); // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly string[]'
```

**as const**

```
const arr2 = ["test3", "test4"] as const; 

arr2.push() // Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly ["test3", "test4"]'.
```

Whats difference?

Comment: @Jesper absolutely not.

Comment: Spectr, it _is_ a dup only that the answers that got more votes are missing important context. IMO the accepted answer should have been: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038484/1057429  for more info, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties and here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Comment: I added an additional answer which may accommodate the specifics of this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68457385/1057429

Comment: @NirAlfasi ty (+1)