# Is there a way for Typescript to warn about object assignment into another object as a reference assignment

Tags: typescript

For example this is allowed in Typescript
EDIT: Left original code example that was originally attempted to be solved. A better example is below

```js
const initObj = { a: 1, b:  2 }

const usableObj = {
    x: initObj
}
usableObj.x.a = 2

const usableObj2 = {
    x: initObj
}
console.log(usableObj2.x.a) // output is 2 but initObj.a = 1

// To get around this you have to assign via spread
const initObj = { a: 1, b: 2 }

const usableObj = {
    x: {...initObj}
}
usableObj.x.a = 2

const usableObj2 = {
    x: {...initObj}
}
console.log(usableObj.x.a) // output 2
console.log(usableObj2.x.a) // output 1
```

An optional warning sign for creating a reference would be helpful. I would rather not use a class creating extra compiled code to create a class with an interface for a simple constant object. Assignment to the constant is okay but creating a reference from a constant object might be something to warn about.

Readonly on a class is nice and have used but I would not like to deal with this classes in Redux which this is where the issue is happening. Since I am using an object to hold information in state this is a fault that can cause issues when "attempting" to reset state.

Any settings for this warning?

EDIT: example use case code with actual issue comes up, above was an attempt at a simpler example but did not have the same issues when tested against tests given by others

```js
// usage example (the base of where the issue was found)
interface InitObj {
    a?: boolean
    b?: number
}
const initObj: InitObj = {
    a: false,
    b: 1
}
interface IReducer {
    init_obj: InitObj
}
const initReducer: IReducer = {
    init_obj: initObj
}

interface IAction {
    type: string
    payload: InitObj
}

function Reducer(action: IAction, state: IReducer = initReducer) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'test1':
            Object.assign(state.init_obj, {
                ...action.payload
            })
            return {...state}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

let change1 = Reducer({ type: 'test1', payload: {a: true}}, initReducer)
console.log(`change1: ${JSON.stringify(change1)}`)
let change2 = Reducer({ type: 'test1', payload: {b: 2}}, change1)
console.log(`change2: ${JSON.stringify(change2)}`)
let reset = Reducer({type: 'test1', payload: initObj}, change2)
console.log(`Reset reducer: ${JSON.stringify(reset)}`) // should reset to { a: false, b: 1}
```

[New example with Object.freeze error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3&ssl=37&ssc=38&pln=36&pc=38#code/PTAEFcGcEMHMFNTwB7QLYAcA2iAUAXAC0QCNpJEB7AM1AHdiAnRIxAS0knETvNGsrgAdgBMAlACg2Q-PEbVoAY0QBJIW3wB5EgCtQAbwmhjoaAH4AXKBKVKOaEKMmSl0EPBoSciQF8JiyiFIfFBpDW0dKzVw3VAAXgMnY2grBSwKABok6ysARl8pGTkFZVAVACV4EXBlRkSTUPV8AH1KXSimiIKAoJCw-Erq2qjBmrl4+pN+1vbGmJ0Cwtl5JVUAQUV8NkDJ43wATwx4K2DGaVhsjGh9rEpoEQ75xephTe2hUFHa3CUtwKiNn8hBlQMFoLIRlUxnUEv0vnIxLtQXQNIpCD83oEAHQHI6IwwNBqKciIADksmCuVJFmyhJMEXgmyx5EgbFgQlwYNkWOmbR0IIJdKFxixoq58B5TRm-NpwpMouZmKEWKuNzuIlldJ8kjlJmY+HAjA++gV4r8wpE8AU4Cw+BpuuM+sNH3F2T8fgkOBCaIcCFyE3hjFw+lAuOOoHJ8EppJBqtu9ys+hSocY3B8PhBcKhtUkPUgdglt1guAABj6hH6rAASfQAKQAypoAHJY07nNjUfa4ct+sQ+EuSL2gHvwABMAezcmDocO4cj0dj13jDwMJCso-TIJHuVzgXzOCxRdLI9H1brjZbbYrHa7J77A898BCzAoIQSgeDYas8-wVMXaoTOYtF0DNh0IX0x13IIC0PShixLSpX1AZghjkM8G2bVt8DOa9O1wF8n3vREQFBQhBCwERkKjJ9Q0oAxTFSaB0ngEE11AXIPRIqA4B4DRCFABkmWoZh4AAL3gfw9z6TpdFPMoZL0BJBPwLFhPgMT4GDbJkzSTJsjY-JtUk3ogMDOSKknGEkV5WZ+giUdnleIFPks0cMSBAElRBcVIVQqysz80d8WySAUXwNF3PeHFZ2C4ViQoCMKV-alNUJZTmU4NkOXFSUNGlAVUuFU18HBCUbJlB1CQVX4orjdVCpMIzKqdI0DGK0rzSFS1rVte0HRal0StkN1FiHRR-XfVzpy-RKo2S-9l0TZNsLTIy8xgo8S2YRRwEtRhx23dCLywnDYBvbsd37QcaMUcdJsC6bZ2-JK-1AOrAP0NiN1A8aoP3Qs4NLFDoQO8CKzHI7MKvM68NuojH2fCcHv0Gaf1e96Vzs2SfqC4z-tg+DEJo4HalAOSawwy9sPbPCCPwIjQBIyAyJtSi6do+idKYzIcnYnwgA)
[Example with fix - this is fine, but would like a warning on the assignment from typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFcGcEMHMFNTwB7QLYAcA2iAUAXAC0QCNpJEB7AM1AHdiAnRIxAS0knETvNGsrgAdgBMAlACg2Q-PEbVoAY0QBJIW3wB5EgCtQAbwmhjoaAH4AXKBKVKOaEKMmSl0EPBoSciQF8JiyiFIfFBpDW0dKzVw3VAAXgMnY2grBSwKABok6ysARl8pGTkFZVAVACV4EXBlRkSTUPV8AH1KXSimiIKAoJCw-Erq2qjBmrl4+pN+1vaDADoF-oifUBBQJnZIeg3QVlBFQgcEN3gqrfxKdegMDHghObLaETZmRXwsAE9TTjZYISrGjE9MxqHI7qUOFx4FtrrdoIwCoVZPIlKoAIJvNiBSbGfAfW5WYKMaSwbIYaAfLCUaAiDpAxHUYSY7GjWq4JT4LFCKIYzmBDKgYLQWQjKpjOoJfQLOb9VlyHxiHGCugaA7s5n3PG3RWGBoNRTkRAAclkwVyRos2T1Jgi8Dec3IkF+QlwQtkMqaMx0At11r9xmlbvgHo0Xqy-v90o5XLm5Mp1JEVr9CqT1uY+HAjCE8wWQb8-pE8AU4Cw+EtEZM6cz2aD2T8fgkOBCByO8FyEzljFw+l2+PgVhN0Pw5oFcapNKs+hSu0Y3B8KZ6kDswapsFwAAMW0IELkrAASfQAKQAypoAHJzIkktjUD64Lc7sQ+deSJv7Q7b+AAJg7YrZPa1ftQEHM0jVHClx1pAwSCsL95wFB820kRdlzmVcN0Qr99yPU8LyvbcbzvTCnxfRt4BCZgKBCBJO27QCB1NYcwNAMcEysJZdB8BCPwQL9kMCJccDQyg13XSoqNAZghjkbCT3PS98GJAjb1wSjyJIxU1kgQhBCwERJOhcjdkuHtpzSTIclAXIfCAA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Nd4QnN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: *"The initObj should be immutable"* - why do you think so? Declaring the variable as `const` does not make the object immutable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between const and readonly in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561155/difference-between-const-and-readonly-in-typescript)

Comment: @kaya3 I think that's what OP wants to achieve, rather than a statement for how the language works.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, but the OP seems to think the second object is needed to exhibit the problem, when in reality `initObj.a = 42` can perfectly well mutate the object already.

Comment: @kaya3 it demonstrates that you can assign the object directly elsewhere. Instead OP doesn't want that to be possible. The problem isn't that `initObj` is mutable. It's that assigning it elsewhere can still mutate it. Thus *copying* the object instead of directly assigning it keeps all of them independent, so each can be updated independently.

Comment: @jcalz Typescript playground example added. @kaya3 I mean it to have a warning available as an option. also readonly can only be applied within an object when I need the original initObj to be readOnly. Also the issue is not that `initObj.a` can be assigned a new value its that a reference was made from `initObj`

Comment: @VLAZ If the object were immutable then assigning it elsewhere, it would still be immutable as a member of the second object. The OP is not looking for a way of making the object only mutable via the original reference; they want it to be immutable, which is not what `const` achieves nor is it what `const` is meant to achieve, but the question as written makes it look like OP thinks `const` is meant to achieve this. Otherwise I don't know why they used a second object to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: *"also readonly can only be applied within an object when I need the original initObj to be readOnly"* - I don't understand the issue here. You want `initObj` to be readonly so you need to apply `readonly` within that object. If you declare it as `const initObj: {readonly a: number, readonly b: number} = ...` then you get what you want, including the error when trying to reassign its properties via the other reference. You can more succinctly do the same thing with `const initObj = ... as const`.

Comment: @kaya3 OP *does* want to update the object. See the last example where `usableObj` is updated. However, the example demonstrates what OP wants to achieve - changing `usableObj` does not affect `initObj` (and through it `usableObj2`). The first + second example shows what *currently* happens and that it's undesirable: changing `usableObj` mutates shared data.

Comment: const does not mean immutable.... you made the variable called initObj cannot be assigned to again becaus its a const.... but nothing is preventing you from changing the values of the fields in the object

Comment: @VLAZ The question was edited one minute ago, before that it said *"The initObj should be immutable"*. So according to the question when I commented, the OP did not want to update the object.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9Jl8m) meet your needs?  If not, please [edit] your example code with use cases that fail if you do it this way.

Comment: @kaya3 and OP didn't want to update it. Through a shared reference. That's what I understood but I do recognise that "immutable" might have been slightly misleading. After OP clarified, it's exactly how I read the question first "This question shouldn't be updated after assigning it elsewhere", rather than "this object should not be mutable at all".

Comment: @jcalz working on a new example closer to use case. Currently in redux using `Object.freeze` causes a runtime error so working on an update that portrays this in the example

Comment: @jcalz example created. Spread always fixes the issue, applying Object.freeze doesn't work without spread, also using readonly does not work without spread. Just using spread by itself works without Object.freeze and without readonly on the property.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee immutability of `initObj`, you can [freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it to prevent further assignment. And if you want to restrict this only on type level and allow in runtime (might be for performance reasons, for example), you can properly type `usableObj`.

```js
const initObj = Object.freeze({ a: 1, b: 2 });

const usableObj = {
    x: initObj
}
console.log('Regular obj assignment')
usableObj.x.a = 2
console.log(`Should be 1: ${initObj.a}`)

console.log('Assignment via spread')
const initObj2 = { a: 1, b: 2 }
const usableObj2 = {
    x: {...initObj2}
}
usableObj2.x.a = 2
console.log(`should be 2: ${usableObj2.x.a}`)
console.log(`should be 1: ${initObj2.a}`)
```

- [Frozen example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOUDyAjAVjAvDN6CmwUAdAGYBO++AXvgBQDeMAhgFwwCMANDKuwEwwAvgEoA3ACgJoSLACuEZqgA2+PNhgMJMHTAAe7BEjwSh08BBCriykAHM6AcgBK+O3OXNyMEBhYQIODswAFt8MChHEQkFJVU8Yj1iZg1+c0grfBt7OgADAGUACxAPABNefE52ABIGIxQMZKFc6PTLa1sHRwBBAKDQ8NgANzgUiAAHSmZSqLbYerxBHCY2Th4+GEEzGWgYWJU1DCXNbV0DTWJLhaOzM334o8Tk1LbM7IdciGKyis2ahnuh3Q-CezGa0R2b06eS+JWU5VQlQ4-2uwKaLSAA)

```js
const initObj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

type UsableObj = {
    x: Readonly<typeof initObj>;
}

const usableObj: UsableObj = {
    x: initObj
}
console.log('Regular obj assignment')
usableObj.x.a = 2
console.log(`Should be 1: ${initObj.a}`)

console.log('Assignment via spread')
const initObj2 = { a: 1, b: 2 }
const usableObj2: UsableObj = {
    x: {...initObj2}
}
usableObj2.x.a = 2
console.log(`should be 2: ${usableObj2.x.a}`)
console.log(`should be 1: ${initObj2.a}`)
```

- [Typed example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOUDyAjAVjAvDA3jAQwC4YBGAGhlRICYYBfAbgChmoBPABwFMYBVCAVQAbbmkw5czGDJgAPEgCVuBACbhh7ADwceIAGbxEKDAD4W9VqEiwAroJFiMJAUNHjseabIVGk45ktrCBBRADphEABzAAoAcmUo22ECACcYEAxCCAg4KLAAW24wKDiASmZ7Nyd0MLkwgk8aZmDQ7gjomIADAGUACxBk1SpeUhIAElwEfwwG+i6KlvAQ8MjYuIBBHLzC4tgANzhGiE5UlVVypZs-E3Q6SUISCipaBivoGCrHcRoXB3cspJvDJfLgwuDprcaJZLF8AXc6g0mu82h1Yl0IAMhiMYL8YJM4TUaIiCPMKq1Vp0MVjhMNUKMJlNjD85gsgA)

Comment: Please put the code as plain text in your post in addition to Playground links.

Comment: Updated the question and link to a better example of the use case

Comment: This is less of an answer than it is a link to an answer.

Comment: using Object.freeze does work but you still need to spread the object on assignment. It doesn't give a compile time error only a runtime error. Which I am actually asking if there is a setting in Typescript to have a reference assignment warning. I see that this does work but it is just more code than just spreading the object anyways.

Comment: The "Typed example" shows it working on spread too, at compile time. Your link "Example with fix - this is fine, but would like a warning on the assignment from typescript" does not apply `Readonly<>` to the property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The point is that there is no typescript warning, not that spread is the fix. But also with Readonly applied it still does not work unless spread is used.

Comment: If you want to allow only spread for assignment, you can complement typescript with custom ESLint rule for this, but not sure if it will be universal enough to be not over restrictive

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog that rule doesn't apply to the current question. I am looking for an optional warning on assignment of an object by reference.

Comment: You always assign object by reference in JavaScript. You can't do it in any other way. And JS and TS don't care if it is an old object or a new object. It is easier to actually create new object underneath via proxy or setter (if you into setters), than to make a warning or error.