# What is the difference between readonly and const assertion for class properties?

Tags: typescript

Could someone clarify to me, what is the difference between the two following notations in TypeScript?

```
class Test {
  readonly ANSWER = 42;
}
```

and

```
class Test {
  ANSWER = 42 as const;
}
```

The first is a [readonly modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier), while the second is called [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). Both concepts are well-documented and explained on multiple places, yet they both seem to do the same thing to me, in this simple case at least, i.e. making the property immutable. Even their combination seems to be valid:

```
class Test {
  readonly ANSWER = 42 as const;
}
```

So why are they both allowed syntax and is there any advantage or a disadvantage in using one over the other?

To clarify further: I am fully aware of the difference between regular [const and readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561155/difference-between-const-and-readonly-in-typescript). I am specifically interested in the difference between const assertion and readonly.

Comment: The type is the value of the literal, rather than the type of the literal. Your const assertion link explains this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readonly ANSWER = 42` describes the assignability of a property. Typescript is smart enough to know that no other value can ever be assigned, so it's safe to infer as specific a type as possible. In this case `42` instead of `number`

Where `ANSWER = 42 as const` describes the type of a value and forces a constant inference of the type, instead of the default of `number`.

They are very different things.

Here's a better example:

```
class Test1 {
  ANSWER = 42 as const;

  set42() {
    this.ANSWER = 42 // fine
  }
}

class Test2 {
  readonly ANSWER = 42;

  set42() {
    this.ANSWER = 42 // error
  }
}
```

Here `Test1`'s `ANSWER` has a value type of the numeric literal value `42`. You can assign anything you want to that property as long as it's `42`. Without `as const` the type would be inferred as `number` instead, and allow any number to assigned.

However, `Test2`'s `ANSWER` cannot be reassigned, even if it's the right type because it is `readonly`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=2&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=24#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBGaBvAsAKGtAggHIDKA6gKIBK0AvNACwBM0k0wA9gHbIDcOOeCPCRMAFAEoMAvNCQALAJYQAdETJVaDZgHpt0AGYLO8aQF8c57DlCQYCZMyy5oAJ3hgAJlxABPAiQpqOiY+K2chEUYJKWc8eSVVAI1gnT14Fxd2FzMLIA)

---

The difference is more apparent with more complex types:

```
class Test1 {
  obj = { a: 123 } as const;
  // Test1.obj: { readonly a: 123; }

  setObj() {
    this.obj = { a: 123 } // fine
  }

  setObjProp() {
    this.obj.a = 456 // error
  }
}

class Test2 {
  readonly obj = { a: 123 };
  // Test2.obj: { a: number; }

  setObj() {
    this.obj = { a: 123 } // error
  }

  setObjProp() {
    this.obj.a = 456 // fine
  }
}

class Test3 {
  readonly obj = { a: 123 } as const;
  // Test3.obj: { readonly a: 123; }

  setObj() {
    this.obj = { a: 123 } // error
  }

  setObjProp() {
    this.obj.a = 123 // error
  }
}
```

Here the `readonly` modifier on `Test2` fails to infer the more specific type of `{ a: 123 }` and instead falls back to `{ a : number }`.

But while the `Test2.obj` property is readonly, the object assigned it remains mutable. So `this.obj.a = 456` is valid, and why `{ a: number }` is the inferred type.

Where with `as const` the object itself is readonly, so it cannot be mutated.

When you combine both `readonly` and `as const` you declare an immutable property with a value that is also immutable.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=38&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBGaBvAsAKGtA9gEYBW0AvBtGAFzQoBMAzNAL5UzD4B2yA3DngD0guIlQA6IsVrpoAJ3hgAJtxABPKrQaNerHAOgR4SAPIkAFAEoMBvEgAWASwiSS5SjTpNW0YdABmjlzwBiz6uIbGZsQACnL4AA5WNhF2Ti5S4mDuACwArABsviLwcvFyoThh2DigkDAIyPQpeArKqhpS7rKe2qz8EX6NSPSu0h60XACuALaEpbrVBkamFtZYqdAOzmPdml7MbH6l5ZU1ESvRcYnJG3hpO5nZFPlFfoHBZ0vYdVCiyMw7vJFCouOoCG4KD0tN42JBoJweEgBkIRMMUGMZMD2mCNL0mItwnhLmsWvdthlIRMDj5jmV8BUIt9iVESNckutbFt0mMsrlCsVoCcGV8gA)